# Non-linear programming library in C++

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization

I'm looking for recommendations for C++ libraries for non-linear programming (*not just for integers!*).

Preference is for actively maintained F/OSS solutions, but actively maintained commercial solutions offering free evaluation versions are acceptable.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** As requested, here are more details:

The application I'm working on is simple, and it's about minimizing polynomials of degree 4 and higher (up to 11) with a small set (~20) of constraints expressed as inequalities (again, as polynomials, degree <= 4). I might also, occasionally, have to throw in some trigonometric function, though. In any case, it's always continuous, differentiable functions I'm dealing with. The number of variable ranges from 1 to 12, for now, and won't go much beyond that.

Finally, I need a solution that works on Windows, but cross-platform ones would be preferable.

Comment: Could you give us examples of calculations you want to perform ? In which field (finance ? physics ?) ? On which OS ? (rather *nix or Windows?)

Comment: Please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) has solid C code for a good dozen algorithms, including [COBYLA](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms#COBYLA_.28Constrained_Optimization_BY_Linear_Approximations.29),
Constrained Optimization BY Linear Approximations for derivative-free optimization with nonlinear inequality and equality constraints, by M. J. D. Powell.
Added: [here](https://github.com/denis-bz/opt/tree/master/nlopt)
are runs of several of the non-derivative optimizers in `NLopt`.
For Rosenbrock and Powell test functions in 5d and 10d, they're all *very* sensitive to random startpoints; ymmv.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure, but maybe [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) from CERN will be suitable for you. This is really huge library ([ROOT::Math::Polynomial](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/ROOT__Math__Polynomial.html) class, for example) from CERN itself.

I must say, it's not a 'one-minute-to-learn' library indeed, but has both: **console** to work with all math stuff in real time (looks similar to MathCAD cmd line) and **libs** and **dlls** you can link with your code statically. And it's a cross platform library. More to say, the most powerful feature of the ROOT is that you can build almost all kind of charts and plots.

Comment: Could you please provide a link (in your answer) to the classes doing nonlinear programming?

Answer (score 4):

The most robust such library I know of is [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt).

It is astonishingly robust, it gave me results for chemical engineering problems that I could not solve even with commercial solvers. Look at the [success stories](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/wiki/SuccessStories) for further examples of application.

Comment: @Denis I have no access to a Mac so I cannot tell for sure. However [these instructions](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/wiki/Ipopt_on_Mac_OS_X) seems well maintained and they are from Mar 14, 2012. I think it is worth a shot.